# How to style html select tag arrow?

Tags: html, css

I want to change a select tag arrow with an image, and also I want to have another image as hover state, and one for pressed state. And I should do that with CSS2.1 (no CSS3 solution please). How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whenever I need to style selects I use http://jamielottering.github.com/DropKick/

Comment: Did you try this: https://github.com/KensoDev/Stylish-Select ? I want to know if you have tried and still prefer DropKick?

Comment: I haven't tried that however dropkick was chosen because it works perfectly with asp:dropdown's that have events triggered on change. Dropkick handles these events perfectly and it is really easy to create multiple themes for selects as well. However I will definitely have a look as you never know when something better may come along

Answer (score 0):

U can use background-image property in "element name":hover,"element":visited

Comment: But it does not overlap the arrow.

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible to do with just CSS, you will have to make use of JavaScript to accomplish it.

Answer (score 0):

The only crossbrowser way to style form fields other than text fields and buttons is using JavaScript to implement custom form-controls.